# How to recover event in an message driven architecture

Tags: architecture, message-queue, messaging, event-sourcing

I was just wondering what are the standard approaches for recovering,replaying messages in message driven architecture.

Take for instance

A consumer unexpectedly dies before completing the event and updating the status to complete or what if the event is taking
longer than usual to complete.

Each event will have a row on a table so that we can track the event. Lets say the replay is triggered when an event row has not
been updated for some period of time say 15 minutes and the status is not complete.

In either case where a consumer dies
unexpectedly or an event is taking more than 15 minutes. A replay would be triggered. This will result in duplicate events for
the same message.

One approach to solve the hung process is to have a timeout and kill the process after that. Is there other ways?

Answer (score 2):

It is expected that on failure the event will be redelivered. So the event processing must be idempotent.

How exactly the idempotency is achieved depends on a specific use case.

Comment: Okay so the idempotency will protect the data from getting into an inconsistent state. However the redeliveries could flood the system, I guess theres not much to do in that case except add some backoff time before replaying.

Comment: That's why you don't build such solutions yourself as you'll end up dealing with this and many other potential failure modes. Use existing ones. Check out my project temporal.io, for example.

Comment: Interesting, will check it out